# Variable length unordered inputs for a deep neural network

Tags: deep-learning

I have a function $f(x_1, x_2) = Y$ and the goal would be a user gives me a variable list of Y's where each Y was generated from the same constant $x_2$ parameter but $x_1$ varies.

I want my program to give my best guess of $x_2$. I'd like to try and train a deep neural network to do this.

A few problems is that the order of Y that the user can give me will be random and the number of Y's will vary as well. I'd hope the more Y's they gave me the more accurate my prediction of what $x_2$ would be is.

I'm not quite sure how to setup a model where it's unordered with variable length inputs.

**Example**

$f(x_1, x_2) = x_1 \cdot x_2 + noise$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $\in \mathbb{R}^3$

$x_2$ is unknown and I'm giving lots of examples where $x_2$ is fixed but $x_1$ varies

I don't know what $x_1$ is but I observe the output $f(x_1, x_2)$

I can train the neural network with synthesized data

I'd imagine if the user gave more observations I'd get a more accurate response

Comment: Welcome to Data Science SE. Your question is very broad and may likely get closed for that reason. Try adding data and describing what you have tried so far. Why do you want to use deep learning and not just a simple optimization?

Comment: I already have solved this using least squares with regularization. I'm trying to learn deep learning and not sure how to setup in this framework. I also don't understand why you say it's very broad - I give the exact inputs and expected outputs - it's a toy problem

Comment: There are many neural networks possible in this context that is why I said is was broad. If this is your first adventure in deep learning / neural nets I highly recommend to do work through [these examples](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples). They will learn you how to tackle your problem.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and added a concrete example. I have worked through a bunch of examples but generally the X input has been fixed sizes

Comment: When trying to find $x_2$ from the user-supplied examples, do you know the form of $f(x_1,x_2)$ or is that also hidden? That makes a big difference to approach. Also, can the system be trained on more examples than the user supplies? If the form of the function is hidden and also we have no information other than the user-supplied data plus that there is a fixed param and a variable one, then I think it is not solvable to find the fixed param in general . . .

Comment: Yes, I know the model. In my case it's basically dot($x_1, x_2$) where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $\in \mathbb{R}^3$. I want to try more complicated models later but this is a good starting point for me. I know $x_2$ isn't changing but I don't know what either $x_1$ or $x_2$ is and I'm only fed $Y$ as my observations. Yes, the system will be trained with lots of examples.

Comment: You *only* have a sequence of Y's? So you don't know the `x1` values? Do you have any constraints on the population of `x1` - without that I think it is intractable. For instance, in your example, there is an incomputable scale factor whatever series you are given, unless you know something about how `x1` is being generated by the user.

Comment: $x_1$ and $x_2$ are normalized so they are constrained to the unit sphere.